# HDRI appears blocky (past blurry)

Tags: hdri

[image]

This is a 1K HDRI I'm using and it appears extra blocky, past the point of being called blurry. Last I worked on it it wasn't like this and at least I could define what was in the image. Now it's just blocky. I feel like this isn't a problem with 1k image because 8k appears the same. Anyone know the cause?
Thanks

blend file [image]

Comment: Could you please pack your image and share your file?

Comment: 1K image looks blurry and blocky exactly like in your image when I test it. That's as expected. 8K image looks sharp. You do not show how 8K image looks in your setup. Are you sure you have an actual 8K image and that it is set up properly? You could change interpolation in the image settings of the node(side/n panel in shader editor, Node Tab with the node selected) Cubic works better than linear with low resolution. This seems like resolution issue in your image and that is what one should expect from 1K image.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys https://polyhaven.com/a/limpopo_golf_course This is the image in use. I have used both 1k and 8k version and they actually appear EXACTLY identical just like the image I posted. (1k and 8k looks the same.)

Comment: @moonboots The HDRI I used is here > https://polyhaven.com/a/limpopo_golf_course.
I have added the blend file in the post.

Comment: There is no problem in your file. You have not packed the textures, but if I download the HDRIs separately it works exactly as expected with 1K image an if I add 8K version, it is sharp. Have no idea, what the issue is. Once again - 1K is low resolution, you should not expect good result with it. Changing interpolation helps a little though.

Comment: @Martynas Žiemys it looks like there's a problem with his file, if I open the image with his file it looks pixelated with Cycles, whereas if I create a new file it will look good

Comment: Using 1K image in the question was unnecessarily confusing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have Limit Size enabled for textures in your Preferences( <kbd>F4</kbd>   ->   <kbd>P</kbd> ):

[image]

Make sure it's turned off.

Answer (score 4):

Also I just tested it with my configuration, **Simplify** can have an effect. Be sure to review your values.

With Simplify:

[image]

Without :

[image]

Where to change it:

[image]